# Magento sql query for product details

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I want to query a magento database to show Sku, productname, ProductDetails, price, WholesalePrice and Storedunits.
I have this query

```
       SELECT 
    `e`.`sku`,"
    IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) AS `name`, "
    IF(at_description.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_description_default.value) AS `description` "

     FROM "
    `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` "
    INNER Join "
     `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name_default` "
           ON (`at_name_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND "
              (`at_name_default`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et ON ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'name' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND "
              `at_name_default`.`store_id` = 0 "
    Left Join "
      `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name` "
           ON (`at_name`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND "
              (`at_name`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et ON ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'name' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND "
              (`at_name`.`store_id` = 1) "
    INNER Join "
     `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `at_description_default` "
           ON (`at_description_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND "
              (`at_description_default`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et ON ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'description' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND "
              `at_description_default`.`store_id` = 0 "
    Left Join "
      `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `at_description` "
           ON (`at_description`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND "
              (`at_description`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et ON ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'description' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND "
              (`at_description`.`store_id` = 1)
```

which returns Sku, ProductName and ProductDetails but i can't find the rest of the fields

Comment: What does "can't find the rest of the fields" mean? Please show example input, output, desired output.

Comment: This query above returns sku, productname, productdetails. I want to return the price, WholesalePrice and Storedunits fields but I don't know how to search them

Comment: Thanks but that is just repeating what you said before. What does "search them" mean? Please use more words. Do you want to know what table(s) they are in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [a tutorial](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/eav-database-structure/):

> For example, all prices and other decimal attributes are stored in **catalog_product_entity_decimal** where as all short text strings are stored in **catalog_product_varchar**. To figure out which table each attribute is stored in, Magento uses the column **backend_type** in the table **eav_attribute**.